# log linearization around steady state (price dynamics)

Tags: macroeconomics, new-keynesian-economics, log-linearization

I'm stuck with a derivation from Gali's book.

In the version 2008, I can't get eq. (7) from chapter 3. All is ok until the following:

$$
(1-\epsilon)\log\pi_{t}=\log(\theta+(1-\theta)\exp[(1-\epsilon)(\log{P_{t}^{*}}-\log{P_{t-1}}])
$$

I'm not sure how to do the log-linear approximation of eq. above to get this:

$$
\pi_{t}=(1-\theta)(p^{*}-p_{t-1})
$$

Please if someone could help me I will appreciate it a lot. Thanks!